# Django: extend Admin for all users

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm creating a multi user blog in Djano and would like to use the `Admin` view for all users to provide functionality to create, edit, and delete posts.

I found [this](http://blog.tryolabs.com/2012/06/18/django-administration-interface-non-staff-users/) tutorial which explains the use of Admin for non-staff users. However, I am getting an error

```
cannot import name user_admin_site
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite

class UserAdmin(AdminSite):
    pass

user_admin_site = UserAdmin(name='user')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.admin import user_admin_site

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^', include(user_admin_site.urls)),
     url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

Comment: do you have myapp in the installed_apps settings ?